# Never delete recentf entries

Tags: recentf

I have all my files in `recentf`, weeks of file visiting history ; But recently, entries have been randomly disappearing ; This is disrupting my workflow in a big, bad way. Questions:

1. How can I make sure that no external package is tampering with my `recentf` file?
2. If the former is not possible, then, is there a way to "watchdog" this file so that I know if and when something is being written to it?

Comment: Check `recentf-max-saved-items`?

Comment: @NickD I'll be damned... I was fairly certain I had it configured this way, but then I looked, and no, so thanks, I `cutomize`'d it to 0 (you should put that as an answer and I'll OK it) let's see :)

Comment: IIRC, it should be nil, not 0 (but haven't gone back to check).

Comment: @NickD: Please consider posting your comment as an answer (assuming the Q is not a duplicate). Comments can be deleted at any time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Customize `recentf-max-saved-items` and set it to `nil`. The doc string of the variable (`C-h v recent-max-saved-items`) says:

> recentf-max-saved-items is a variable defined in ‘recentf.el’.
> Its value is 20
>
> You can customize this variable.
>
> Documentation:
>
> Maximum number of items of the recent list that will be saved.
> A nil value means to save the whole list.
> See the command ‘recentf-save-list’.

Comment: If you want to maintain a reasonable recentf list, you will probably need to exclude some paths customizing the variable recentf-exclude.